# My menu component of material ui is giving my page an extra margin to the right when i click on the menu icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

1. This is my menu component.

```
             <Menu
              id="Menu-Btn"
              aria-labelledby="Menu-Btn"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left",
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left",
              }}
              TransitionComponent={Fade}
              PaperProps={{
                style: {
                  marginTop: "40px",
                },
              }}
            >
```

**When i click on the menu icon one rendering MenuItems my whole page gets a margin of right**

Comment: Hi, i don't see any issue in menu component. share your page code. when menu items/modal opens the right side scrollbar disappear. so need to check page code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:
disableScrollLock={true}